# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04. Bootloader not working

Tags: bootloader, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 without any other OS's on the drive using LIVE USB.. But OS is not working. I tried Bootrepair but no luck to fix it.. This is bootinfo http://paste2.org/Ca5aOyHa . can someone pls help to fix it

It shows error when i boot

```
error: file'/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.nod'
Entering rescue mode.....
grub rescue >
```

Comment: can you please expand on what you mean by OS is not working. What is happening? What errors if any ... What do you see if anything? "not working" doesn't give anyone a clue as to where to start

Comment: Hello Srikanth and welcome to Askubuntu! There is one thing about what you posted that jumps out at me: You installed Ubuntu with a Live USB, which requires UEFI support on your computer, but your drive is configured for the traditional BIOS/MBR method. It seems that your computer is in UEFI mode, which means it won't be able to detect your drive's MBR configuration. Are you able to enter your BIOS and switch it from UEFI mode to Legacy mode?